# Updating Labels within Grid from ObservableCollection

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I am currently working with an app in Xamarin, building it for UWP.

In this app, I have a Stack that has an image of the human body with other images overlayed (colored circles). What I am trying to do is place a Label on top of the circles on the body and update them in real time based on data within an ObservableCollection (called TagInfoList) I am pulling from another file. To set this up, I have made a 5x4 Grid that the Body image takes up the entirety of, and have placed the circles within individual cells of the Grid. Additionally, the Labels go in their own cells. The issue I am running into is getting my Labels to show up and actively update from my TagInfoList.

[Here is what I am trying to set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6k87.png). I want my Labels to go on top of the colored circles.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"> <!-- Body Model Section -->

      <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="400" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <!-- 4 equal size Columns-->
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <!-- 5 equal size Rows -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.body.png}" Aspect="AspectFit" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
        <Image Source="{pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.green.png}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFit" Opacity="0.6"/>
        <Image Source="{pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.red.png}"   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Opacity="0.6"/>
        <Image Source="{pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.green.png}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Aspect="AspectFit" Opacity="0.6"/>
        <Image Source="{pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.green.png}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFit" Opacity="0.6"/>
        <Image Source="{pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.red.png}"   Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit" Opacity="0.6"/>

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding TagInfoList}">
          <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SensorAvgValue}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SensorAvgValue}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding SensorAvgValue}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SensorAvgValue}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SensorAvgValue}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
      </Grid>
    </StackLayout> <!-- Body Model Section -->
```

I've tried putting the Labels within a CollectionView since I can bind it to the TagInfoList, something a Grid cannot do. However, I am unsure what changes I need to make with the hierarchy of my objects to get the Labels to actively update. The TagInfoList and SensorAvgValue that I am calling are both updating correctly in other StackLayout instances, so I know there is no issue with the ObservableCollection.

In addition, my next step will be to make the Images change based on the value in the Label, so I may need to also move the Image objects to whatever level the Labels are at so they can interact with each other.

If this would be easier to do in a .xaml.cs file, I could also transfer the code to one. One exists but it's only there for one part of a different Stack in my layout.

Any and all advice would be appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: it would probably help to post a mockup of what you're trying to achieve.  If you want each Label aligned with one of the circles, then placing them in a CollectionView won't help you

Comment: if your Observable Collection is only changing in values (and not in length) then you will not trigger an event. You will need to implement the iNotifyPropertyChanged event handler. Additionally, x:bind default is OneTime and it should be set to OneWay. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Jason I have added a mockup image to the post. I want to put my Labels on top of the colored circle Image objects that have been placed on the body model.

Comment: you are already using a Grid for the images, so if you want the labels on top of the images, just place them in the same grid cells.  CollectionView is absolutely not the way to do this.

Comment: @Jason I've removed my collectionview, and my main goal now is updating my Label text based on the ObservableCollection mentioned in my post. I can assign an ItemsSource within my Grid, but I'm not sure how the Binding works to my label values from there. Do I need an OnPropertyChanged for a Grid object? Or for the label object?

Comment: I have no idea what `TagInfoList` is or how it corresponds to the images in your UI.  Does the nth element of the collection always correspond to the same color?  If so then you can just bind each `Label` using `{Binding TagInfoList[0].SensorAvgValue}` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as the user Jason mentioned: a mockup would be nice. anyway...

If you just want an Image and a batch over it, wrap it into a "**[BatchView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/badgeview)**".

Another easy way would be if you place all (Image, Label, Batch(?)) into an "**[AbsolutLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout)**" and then Position it, as the AbsolutLayout is like an overlay.

Finally set it all to a Binding with [OnPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.onpropertychanged?view=xamarin-forms), so it will update itself like in a CollectionView - in a CollectionView it's the same mechanism but automated.

Just draw an simple mockup and post ;)

Comment: I have just added a mockup in the post. I want my labels to go on top of the colored image circles.